# android: In which cases Push Notification get fails delivering on devices

Tags: android, zend-framework, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using gcm.jar on client side and gcm Zend framework on server side for sending push notification. There are about 100 devices registered for push notification, on firing notification even though I receive successful message, push not getting delivered on some of the devices, May I know what would be the various reasons for failures and how to handle them. Any suggestion will be appreciated,

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you detect if the notification was fired or not?

Comment: Were you able to debug it and reproduce a scenario when you would send a notification to your device and it didn't fire?

Comment: on third-party server I firing the notification, and checking response message.