# what does it mean "if the device is connected to GCM"

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I need to implement push notification feature in one of my application. I gone through the android documentation GCM Advance topic [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#unreg).

In the second paragraph i.e

"In the best-case scenario, if the device is connected to GCM, the screen is on, and there are no throttling restrictions (see Throttling), the message will be delivered right away."

Here what does it mean "if the device is connected to GCM"? is this some thing relates to the internet connectivity.

Please share your views on this for better understanding.

Thank you.

Comment: I think it relates to internet (IP) connectivity. And I also find the phrasing slightly confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it relates to internet connectivity.

> Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that allows you
>   to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device.
>   This could be a lightweight message telling your app there is new data
>   to be fetched from the server (for instance, a movie uploaded by a
>   friend), or it could be a message containing up to 4kb of payload data
>   (so apps like instant messaging can consume the message directly).

more [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). Basically the above sentence means that it needs internet connectivity. If you go further on GCM related links you will find the permissions list which has internet permission.

Answer (score 3):

GCM stands for "Google Cloud Messaging". So "if the device is connected to GCM" basically means that your device is:

1) Connected to internet

2) Has an active connection to GCM, which implies that:

- it is not being blocked by your internet provider
- GCM is not down due to any reason, i.e. owerwhelming amount of requests, which is unlikely
- your app is not being blocked from GCM due to incorrect API key or something else
- [...]

Comment: I agree with you, but above mentioned point are not in the hands of developer, It totally depends on individual device on which the app installed correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. And it says further in the sentence you quoted that if the device is connected to GCM, "the message will be delivered right away". And if the device is not connected - the message will be postponed and delivered later, when the device connects to GCM.

Comment: recently I faced an issue, which was also posted on stack over flow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556502/android-in-which-cases-push-notification-get-fails-delivering-on-devices. could you please comment on this issue.